# How can I show automatically make an element appear/disappear based on current time in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there another way to automatically have elements appear and disappear at a certain time than via timeout()? Like ng-if="system.Time>12:00:00" in pseudo code. Preferably only done with html.
What I am aiming at is an offer valid for one hour for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe function like this could be of help:

```js
function timeChecker(){
  if(/*check if item should be visible*/){
    visible = true
  } else {
    visible = false
  }
}

// your timeChecker function will be runned every minute so you can implement more complex logic if needed
var interval = setInterval(timeChecker, 1 * 60 * 1000 /*that would be one minute*/);

// just remember to clear interval when you destroy component
clearInterval(interval);
```